# Logstash input log stream via port

Tags: syslog, logstash

Is there any way to read logstash raw input data that is forwarded via certain port?

input settings are as below

```
input {
    tcp {
          port => 1234
          type => "test"
   }
}
```

and from output config...

```
output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

we can only see the logstash output but not the original input data..

any idea how can i read the input log?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy things in a filter block:

```
filter {
  mutate {
    add_field => { "raw_input": "%{message}" }
  }
}
```

Which will give you the raw input in a `raw_input` field.